# Sitecore Mixed Content error for workflow

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-workflow

We have added a sample workflow for our current site. For some of the environments we have a https connection. When we tried to use the workflow for https we got the error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://site/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?sc_lang=en' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://site//sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Workbox&mo=preview&reload=1&{190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}=0&{46DA5376-10DC-4B66-B464-AFDAA29DE84F}=0&{FCA998C5-0CC3-4F91-94D8-0A4E6CAECE88}=0'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I am using Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

You can see there 3 ids for:

190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC Draft state Id for sample workflow

46DA5376-10DC-4B66-B464-AFDAA29DE84F Awaiting aproval  state Id for sample 
workflow
FCA998C5-0CC3-4F91-94D8-0A4E6CAECE88 Approved  state Id for sample workflow

The problem seems to be on workflow reload

Is there a setting in sitecore workflows that I can set for the workflow to use https urls?

Comment: There's an optional scheme attribute in the site definition, maybe setting that to https might help.